# How can i call intrinsic CUDA math functions?

Tags: math, cuda

I am using visual studio 2013.
Used MFC for the UI and did some heavy calculations in CUDA. 
I am trying to speed up the process, so want to change some functions to intrinsics.
However error message appears that it says not defined.

I think it is something to do with the **CUDACC** because device_functions.h says
if **CUDACC**  need to be defined to use the whole functions.

```
__device__ float cuint2float(int nInput)
{
    return __int2float_rn(nInput);
}
```

How can I enable this option?

Comment: don't get confused by the intellisense error.  Is this actually a build error?

Comment: You were right, It was just a intellisense error.

Comment: @MINSUKLE: Please add an answer explaining this. It is perfectly OK to answer your own questions in [SO]

Answer (score 1):

It was just a intellisense error.
I could execute the program.